# Reference request: Kuratowski limit of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am obtaining the definition of *Kuratowski limit of sets* from wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence), and it refers to the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124292011). I wish to find where exactly the definition of Kuratowski limit of sets but I can't find it in above book... Does anybody know where I can find a hard reference of this definition? (from a book, not wiki)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 335 of the mentioned book, Kuratowski defines

> **Definition** [Kuratowsky: *Topology, Volume I*]. The point $p$ belongs to the *lower limit* $\def\Li{\mathop{\operatorname{Li}}\limits}\Li\nolimits_{n \to \infty} A_n$ of a sequence of sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$, if every neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $A_n$ from a sufficiently great index $n$ onward.

and on page 337 he defines

> **Definition** [Kuratowsky: *Topology, Volume I*]. The point $p$ belongs to the *upper limit* $\def\Ls{\mathop{\operatorname{Ls}}\limits}\Ls\nolimits_{n \to \infty} A_n$ of a sequence of sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$, if every neighbourhood of $p$ intersects an infinite set of the terms $A_n$.

and finally, on page 339 he writes

> **Definition** [Kuratowsky: *Topology, Volume I*]. The sequence of sets $\{A_n\}$ is said to be *convergent to $A$* if $\Li A_n = A = \Ls A_n$. We then write $A = \operatorname{Lim} A_n$($^1$).